# Docker, PhpStorm and PHPUnit -The value of autoloader is specified, but file doesn't exist

Tags: php, docker, phpunit, phpstorm

I'm trying to connect my PhpStorm debugger with PHPUnit. I'm using Docker env and inside docker PHPUnit is working properly. Problem is when I click on "tests" directory PPM -> Run test

I got this:

```
[docker://environment_php_8_fpm:latest/]:php /opt/.phpstorm_helpers/phpunit.php --no-configuration /opt/project/src/tests
Testing started at 16:19 ...
The value of autoloader is specified, but file doesn't exist '/home/kuba/Work/CodeProjects/advertisement-crawler/src/vendor/autoload.php'

Process finished with exit code 1
```

[image]

I tried to find solution in google but its really hard to find something helpful.

@edit
Moreover, i provided new path and i got this after i clicked to refresh
new path is : /opt/project/src/vendor/autoload.php
[image]

And now i have new error message after run this in phpstorm

```
[docker://environment_php_8_fpm:latest/]:php /opt/.phpstorm_helpers/phpunit.php --configuration /opt/project/src/phpunit.xml
Testing started at 18:48 ...

Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class "PHPUnit_TextUI_ResultPrinter" not found in /opt/.phpstorm_helpers/phpunit.php on line 231

Error: Class "PHPUnit_TextUI_ResultPrinter" not found in /opt/.phpstorm_helpers/phpunit.php on line 231

Call Stack:
    0.0006     469784   1. {main}() /opt/.phpstorm_helpers/phpunit.php:0
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Class "PHPUnit_TextUI_ResultPrinter" not found in /opt/.phpstorm_helpers/phpunit.php:231
Stack trace:
#0 {main}
  thrown in /opt/.phpstorm_helpers/phpunit.php on line 231

Process finished with exit code 255
```

i tried to map irectories one more time but still, error
[image]

Comment: Does the file `autoload.php` actually exist in the location specified by the error message? Does it exist in both Docker container filesystem and your host's filesystem?

Comment: to be honest, a dont know which localization should i provide there. I even cant click on this folder icon to select any path. I have to write there by a finger.

Comment: I added few new things to main post.

Comment: What PhpStorm version are you running? Does `/opt/project/src/vendor/bin/phpunit` exist in a container? How do you run the tests using this container outside of PhpStorm?

Comment: In main dir of my app i'm typing something like -> root@00060ed7a04a:/var/www# ./bin/phpunit tests. i dont see any directory in my /opt dir. I mapped directories one more time, you can find this screen in main post

Comment: I am having this too - the PHP interpreter is correctly set to Docker and PHP executes inside docker to run the tests, but PHPStorm is passing in the local (non Docker) option for the configuration file:  --configuration /Users/user/myproject/phpunit.xml instead of its location in the Docker container

Answer (score 0):

My assumption would be that your autoloader file is located in `/home/kuba/Work/CodeProjects/advertisement-crawler/vendor/autoload.php` not in `/home/kuba/Work/CodeProjects/advertisement-crawler/src/vendor/autoload.php` where PhpStorm is looking for it. In your docker file, you have only linked the /src directory. So from docker you can't see files outside of /src.

So I think your mapping in the first case was correct and you should have supplied `/opt/project/vendor/autoload.php`.

Also make sure that you run `composer install` first to actually generate your autoload file.

Answer (score 0):

My problem was that I didn't set Test frameworks (Settings->PHP->Test frameworks) correctly. I added PHP Unit by remote interpreter to use docker-compose and it works.

I found the solution in this [article](https://amandoabreu.com/wrote/setting-up-phpstorm-to-run-phpunit-tests-inside-an-already-running-docker-container/).